# Oblique perspective - projection matrizes in processing

Tags: projection, perspective, processing, projection-matrix

I want to extend processing in order to be able to render 3D stuff with oblique projections (cabinet or cavalier). After looking around source of the camera(), perspective() and ortho() methods I was able to set up an orthographic perspective and then adjust the PGraphics3D#camera matrix to an appropriate value with partial success.

```java
void setup() {
   camera(30, 30, 30, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
   ortho(-100, 100, -100, 100, -500, 500);
   p3d.camera.set(1, 0, -0.433f, 0, 0, 1, 0.25f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}

void draw() {
   box(20);
}
```

This results in the right perspective, but without surface filling. When removing either the camera and ortho method calls or both, the screen is empty, although I'd expect camera(...) to operate on the same matrix that is overwritten later on.

Moreover I'm a little bit confused about the matrizes in PGraphics3D: camera, modelView and projection. While OpenGL keeps two matrix stacks - modelView and projection, here is a third one - camera. Can anybody shed some light on the difference and relation between these matrizes?

This would be helpful in order to know when to use/set which one.

Answer (score 3):

Great question!

I ran the following code as you had it, and it looked like an isometric view of a white cube.

```
1: size(300,300,P3D);
2: camera(30, 30, 30, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
3: ortho(-100, 100, -100, 100, -500, 500);
4: PGraphics3D p3d = (PGraphics3D)g;
5: p3d.camera.set(1, 0, -0.433f, 0, 0, 1, 0.25f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
6: box(20);
```

Here's what's happening:

- Line 2: sets both the **camera** and **modelview** matrices
- Line 3: sets the **projection** matrix
- Line 4: sets the **camera** matrix only, but this actually did nothing here. (read on)

Transformations are only performed using the **modelview** and **projection** matrices.  The **camera** matrix is merely a convenient separation of what the **modelview** is usually initialized to.

If you used the draw() function, the **modelview** matrix is actually initialized to the **camera** matrix before each time it is called.  Since you didn't use the draw() function, your camera matrix was never updated with your oblique transform in your **camera** matrix.

---

### How to create an Oblique Projection

As a disclaimer, you must truly understand how matrices are used to transform coordinates.  Order is very important.  This is a good resource for learning it:
http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html

The quickest explanation I can give is that the **modelview** matrix turns *object* coordinates into relative *eye* coordinates, then the **projection** matrix takes those *eye* coordinates and turns them in to *screen* coordinates.  So you want to apply the oblique projection before the transformation into screen coordinates.

Here's a runnable example for creating a cabinet projection that displays some cubes:

```
void setup()
{
  strokeWeight(2);
  smooth();
  noLoop();

  size(600,600,P3D);
  oblique(radians(60),0.5);
}

void draw()
{
  background(100);

  // size of the box
  float w = 100;

  // draw box in the middle
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  fill(random(255),random(255),random(255),100);
  box(w);

  // draw box behind
  translate(0,0,-w*4);
  fill(random(255),random(255),random(255),100);
  box(w);

  // draw box in front
  translate(0,0,w*8);
  fill(random(255),random(255),random(255),100);
  box(w);
}

void oblique(float angle, float zscale)
{
  PGraphics3D p3d = (PGraphics3D)g;

  // set orthographic projection
  ortho(-width/2,width/2,-height/2,height/2,-5000,5000);

  // get camera's z translation
  // ... so we can transform from the original z=0
  float z = p3d.camera.m23;

  // apply z translation
  p3d.projection.translate(0,0,z);

  // apply oblique projection 
  p3d.projection.apply(
    1,0,-zscale*cos(angle),0,
    0,1,zscale*sin(angle),0,
    0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,1);

  // remove z translation
  p3d.projection.translate(0,0,-z);
}
```

[image: screenshot of oblique projection in processing]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and link. The main error apparently was to set the camera matrix instead of the projection matrix. Still I don't completely get why the above worked as it did and why the filling was missing. I had everything in the setup method except the box drawing itself - corrected my question to be more precise.